# Can you interface with multiple sensors/file descriptors using the same class by creating an object for each sensor?

Tags: c++, class, object, sensors, i2c

So, say I open one sensor using an init(const char *fd) type function, create an object, and run for ex: sensor1.init("/dev/i2c-1") with an input of my 1st sensor location. Then I create a 2nd object and run the same function with another sensor ex. sensor2.init("/dev/i2c-2").

When I use either object to call my other class functions, will they know which file descriptor I am referencing or will this cause conflicts?

Comment: If the class contains the appropriate file descriptor, that the class methods will use, what leads you to believe that they won't know?

Comment: If your class is designed appropriately, this would work fine. It's essentially what `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` do: different objects manage different files.